# Custom structure globally visible for whole symfony2 application

Tags: php, symfony

I need to create custom array and make it global visible, so controllers can use it later. I read about services, but making special class only for storing array sound like a bit exaggeration to me. Is there any other way to do this?

Array is immutable, two-dimensional, like:

```
$races = array(
'human' => array(
  1 => 'tribe1',
  2 => 'tribe2'
),
'dwarf' => array(
  1 => 'drarftribe1'
)
);
```

So its very simple structure.

Comment: Is it an immutable array, i.e. a settings array, or something you have to deal with in different components? Make an example anyway.

Comment: I have edited question - added an example

Comment: Seems to me like a plain entity, why wouldn't you persist it in the data layer?

Comment: Its actually client request to leave it in php code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Then just create a `Races` class, and namespace it wherever you want:

**/src/Acme/YourBundle/Races.php**

```
<?php

namespace Acme\YourBundle;

class Races
{

    static $yourData;

}
```

Whenever you need, refer to `Acme\YourBundle\Races::$yourData`.

Answer (score 1):

```
class GlobalArray {
    static public $data = array();
}
```

Access:

```
$var = GlobalArray::$data[index];
```